# Vaadin: TextField.getValue() doesn't return entered text in CustomLayout

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin application I have a `CustomLayout` panel with a text field:

```
public class BookkeepingView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private TextField userName;
    private PasswordField password;

    public BookkeepingView()
    {
        VerticalLayout contentPanel = new VerticalLayout();

        contentPanel.setStyleName("body");

        contentPanel.addComponent(getHeaderPanel());
        contentPanel.addComponent(getLoginPanel());
        contentPanel.addComponent(getFooterPanel());

        addComponent(contentPanel);
    }

    [...]

    private CustomLayout getLoginPanel() {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setSizeUndefined();
        addComponent(panel);

        CustomLayout customLayoutPanel = new CustomLayout("login");

        userName = new TextField();
        userName.setImmediate(true);
        customLayoutPanel.addComponent(userName, "j_username");
```

When I enter a text into the `userName` text field, press a button with the event handler shown below, I get an empty user name (the tray notification contains the text `User name:`).

```
private void loginButtonPressed() {
    String userName = this.userName.getValue();
    Notification.show("User name:" + userName, Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
}
```

How can I modify the code so that I can read the user-entered value from the `userName` text field in a `CustomLayout` (I need `CustomLayout` in order to easily customise the look and feel of the application) ?

**Update 1 (06.11.2013 18:16 MSK):**

```
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

public class BookkeepingView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    private TextField userName;
    private PasswordField password;

    public BookkeepingView()
    {
        VerticalLayout contentPanel = new VerticalLayout();

        contentPanel.setStyleName("body");


        contentPanel.addComponent(getHeaderPanel());
        contentPanel.addComponent(getLoginPanel());
        contentPanel.addComponent(getFooterPanel());

        addComponent(contentPanel);
    }

    private Component getHeaderPanel() {
        return createCustomLayoutPanel("main-navigation");
    }

    private Component getFooterPanel() {
        return createCustomLayoutPanel("copyright");
    }

    private CustomLayout getLoginPanel() {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setSizeUndefined();
        addComponent(panel);

        CustomLayout customLayoutPanel = new CustomLayout("login");

        userName = new TextField();
        userName.setImmediate(true);
        customLayoutPanel.addComponent(userName, "j_username");

        password = new PasswordField();
        customLayoutPanel.addComponent(password, "j_password");

        final Button loginButton = new Button(I18n.l("bookkeeping_login_button"));
        customLayoutPanel.addComponent(loginButton, "login");

        loginButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                loginButtonPressed();
            }
        });

        return customLayoutPanel;
    }

    private void loginButtonPressed() {
        String userName = this.userName.getValue();
        Notification.show("User name:" + userName, Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
    }

    private CustomLayout createCustomLayoutPanel(final String aHtmlFileName) {
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setSizeUndefined();
        addComponent(panel);

        CustomLayout customLayoutPanel = new CustomLayout(aHtmlFileName);
        return customLayoutPanel;
    }


    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Comment: That should work, are you sure you are reading the value from a correct TextField instance?

Comment: I think Henri is right and maybe you're somehow overwriting your text field, could you please provide the full code?

Comment: @Grove See my update 1.

Comment: I found the cause of the problem - the HTML template was wrong (missing `<div location="...">...</div>` around the text fields).

Comment: If you use a template similar to the example provided in the custom layout intro you shouldn't have any problems: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.customlayout.html